# Can we write custom DOM manipulation inside edit.js file while developing custom Gutenberg block?

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor, editor

I have doubts while creating a custom Gutenberg block are we allowed to directly manipulate DOM?
Below is code that I have written in view.js file I want to know how much portion of this can be moved to edit.js or save.js files?

```js
/**
 * FrontEnd scripts for the example block.
 */

/**
 * Internal dependencies
 */
import './style.scss';

/**
 * Get all the headings and create a table of content.
 */
const headings = document.querySelectorAll(
    '.entry-content :is(h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6)'
);

/**
 * Create a table of content.
 * Make toggle for display less than 768px
 */
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    const tocContainer = document.querySelector(
        '.wp-block-rt-blocks-table-of-contents'
    );
    if (768 > window.innerWidth) {
        const originalSvgString = `
            <svg width="18" height="13" viewBox="0 0 18 13" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <rect width="18" height="1.21935" rx="0.609677" fill="#AB3A6C"/>
                <rect y="11.3789" width="18" height="1.21935" rx="0.609677" fill="#AB3A6C"/>
                <rect y="5.68945" width="18" height="1.21935" rx="0.609677" fill="#AB3A6C"/>
            </svg>
            `;

        const alternateSvgString = `
            <svg width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <rect y="16.8579" width="23.8408" height="1.61502" rx="0.807512" transform="rotate(-45 0 16.8579)" fill="#AB3A6C"/>
                <rect width="23.8408" height="1.61502" rx="0.807512" transform="matrix(-0.707107 -0.707107 -0.707107 0.707107 18 16.8579)" fill="#AB3A6C"/>
            </svg>
            `;

        const originalImg = new Image();
        originalImg.classList.add('original-img');
        originalImg.src =
            'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(originalSvgString);

        // Create a new Image element for the alternate SVG
        const alternateImg = new Image();
        alternateImg.classList.add('alternate-img');
        alternateImg.src =
            'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(alternateSvgString);

        let currentState = 0;

        /**
         * Toggle the SVGs
         */
        const toggleSvg = () => {
            if (0 === currentState) {
                tocContainer.removeChild(originalImg);
                // phpcs:ignore --WordPressVIPMinimum.JS.HTMLExecutingFunctions.insertBefore - This is not a security issue.
                tocContainer.insertBefore(
                    alternateImg,
                    tocContainer.firstChild
                );
                currentState = 1;
                document.querySelectorAll('.toc-item').forEach((item) => {
                    item.style.display = 'flex';
                });
            } else {
                tocContainer.removeChild(alternateImg);
                // phpcs:ignore --WordPressVIPMinimum.JS.HTMLExecutingFunctions.insertBefore - This is not a security issue.
                tocContainer.insertBefore(originalImg, tocContainer.firstChild);
                currentState = 0;
                document.querySelectorAll('.toc-item').forEach((item) => {
                    item.style.display = 'none';
                });
            }
        };

        originalImg.addEventListener('click', toggleSvg);
        alternateImg.addEventListener('click', toggleSvg);

        // phpcs:ignore --WordPressVIPMinimum.JS.HTMLExecutingFunctions.insertBefore - This is not a security issue.
        tocContainer.insertBefore(originalImg, tocContainer.firstChild);
    }

    const headingsCreated = [];
    headings.forEach(function (heading, index) {
        const innerText = heading.innerText;
        const parentAnchor = document.createElement('a');
        parentAnchor.className = 'toc-item';

        const div = document.createElement('div');
        if ('H1' === heading.tagName) {
            div.className = 'heading-h1';
            const divForImage = document.createElement('div');
            divForImage.className = 'icon';
            parentAnchor.appendChild(divForImage);
        } else {
            div.className = 'heading-h2-h6';
        }
        const headingId = 'section' + (index + 1);
        heading.id = headingId;
        parentAnchor.href = '#' + headingId;

        div.innerText = innerText;
        parentAnchor.appendChild(div);

        tocContainer.appendChild(parentAnchor);
        headingsCreated.push(parentAnchor);

        div.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            const element = document.getElementById(headingId);
            const y = element.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY - 36;
            window.scroll({
                top: y,
                behavior: 'smooth',
            });
            const activeElement = document.querySelector('.toc-item.active');
            if (activeElement) {
                activeElement.classList.remove('active');
            }
            if (null !== parentAnchor.querySelector('.heading-h2-h6')) {
                parentAnchor.classList.add('active');
            } else {
                parentAnchor.classList.add('parent-active');
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
});

/**
 * Check if an element is in the viewport.
 * @param {Element} element - The element to check.
 * @return {boolean} - True if the element is in the viewport, false otherwise.
 */
function isInViewport(element) {
    const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    const viewportWidth =
        window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    const viewportHeight =
        window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight;

    return (
        50 >= rect.top &&
        0 <= rect.left &&
        rect.bottom <= viewportHeight &&
        rect.right <= viewportWidth
    );
}

let previousParentActive = null;

/**
 * Add active class to the toc item when the heading is in the viewport.
 */
document.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
    headings.forEach(function (heading) {
        const headingId = heading.id;
        const tocItem = document.querySelector(`[id='${headingId}']`);

        if (tocItem) {
            if (isInViewport(heading)) {
                document.querySelectorAll('.toc-item').forEach((item) => {
                    if (item.innerText !== tocItem.innerText) {
                        item.classList.remove('active');
                    } else {
                        if (null !== item.querySelector('.heading-h1')) {
                            if (previousParentActive) {
                                previousParentActive.classList.remove(
                                    'parent-active'
                                );
                            }
                            item.classList.add('parent-active');
                            previousParentActive = item;
                        }
                        if (null !== item.querySelector('.heading-h2-h6')) {
                            item.classList.add('active');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have doubts while creating a custom Gutenberg block are we allowed to directly manipulate DOM?

Yes but not in the way you've done, that's not how React code works. When a react component is no longer shown it ceases to exist, and the associated DOM node vanishes, along with all its event handlers. *This is both expected and desirable*.

This isn't a WordPress/Gutenberg question, it's more generic than that.

For this reason, using `document.querySelector` on DOM nodes created by React is *very very risky and **fragile***. E.g. blocks that aren't on the screen, or hidden in containers won't be found by the query selector in the code in the question, nor will that list update as headings update/change/move. Headings that are offscreen won't even display in the DOM due to virtual list optimisations.

If you're asking so that you can save time and effort learning React then this will not save you time, and it will not be faster/quicker.

Instead, take a look at the terms and conditions block that already exists, and also take a look at block styles and block variants. Writing a new block from scratch is probably unnecessary

> I want to know how much portion of this can be moved to edit.js or save.js files?

To `save.js` none of it, that would mean the TOC is set in stone and unchangeable in the database until the next time it's saved. This might break your frontend code. Remember, the save component is there to generate a static string of HTML to save in the database, nothing more.

The `edit.js`, not much, the approach taken to get a list of headings won't work well in the editor, it would be easier and more reliable to query the WordPress APIs to get this information than to inspect the DOM for it.

**Hint:** With a null save funciton/component you can render a blocks output in PHP, and even override the output of an existing core block in PHP to print whatever you want. You can even change your edit component to server side rendering to grab the PHP rendered output.

Comment: I got your point but I need to create custom block to display table of content and there h1 and h2-h6 are styled differently that's why I am using `document.querySelector`.
can you provide any reference that I can use to optimize this code?
Thanks.

Comment: you'd be better querying WP data to figure out what the headings are, that's another reason to look at the Table of contents block that already exists. _Why_ does it have to be a custom block? The core custom block can always be overriden to look different on the frontend, have different markup, etc, and even if it was a custom block, using DOM manipulation to query for headings is a dead end that will never work reliably, but these problems were all solved for the TOC block, and the source code is available for all to see and copy from

Comment: Thanks, Tom J Nowell.
I want a custom block so that as per the Figma design given to us ToC matches and I check core ToC but matching its styles with ours would be harder that's why I chose this approach to quickly complete tasks not thinking about optimizations and best approach.

Comment: it would be easier to filter the rendering of the TOC block and instead print your own HTML, then it would be to produce a whole custom TOC block from scratch. Just getting the headings reliably on its own is a harder task then what you were trying to avoid, you've definitely chosen the harder/longer approach. Note that you don't have to make the edit component match the frontend either, it's a nice to have but not necessary, as long as it _approximates_ the frontend it'll do